# how can I manipulate the DOM after a POST request?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to change DOM elements after a post request.

I'm using expressJS, and nodemailer to send form data to my email.
I have a form action to a route and this route has a post request to send the mail. the form it self is in a modal, im trying to display a message on the modal that the message is sent and then hide it.
i tried the onsubmit method, but it doesn't get invoked as the route is loading.

```
app.post("/send-email", (req, res) => {
  let data = {
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    message: req.body.message
  };
  sendMail(data);
});

<form action="/send-email" method="POST" onsubmit="submitForm()">

function submitForm(){
  $("#modalForm").hide();
}
```

excuse me first question on SO

Comment: Is sendMail async?  If so, you could make the $("#modalForm").hide() a callback, or put it after the sendMail() call?

Comment: I dont think it's possible to do that on a server side. it wouldnt work!

Comment: My bad, I thought that was in the DOM.  
You can trigger an async XHR request when the POST is done; and do a callback in the success() event?